# MouseEvent not working in IE, is there another methods?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This construction not working in IE, i would be want to find another way to use it.

```
let evt = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
  clientX: null,
  clientY: null
});

canvas.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: XY problem, don't dispatch an Event here, just call whatever function the event handler calls.

Answer (score -1):

Try to refer example below may help you to solve your issue.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      function writeMessage(canvas, message) {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.font = '18pt Calibri';
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.fillText(message, 10, 25);
      }
      function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
          y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
      }
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
        var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
        writeMessage(canvas, message);
      }, false);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output in IE:

[image]

Reference:

[HTML5 Canvas Mouse Coordinates Tutorial](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/)